# Middleware to optimize postgres

Tags: python, middleware

In my company, we have an ingestion service written in Go whose job is to take messages from a HTTP end point and store them in Postgres. It receives a peak throughput of 50,000 messages/second. However, our database can handle a maximum of 30,000 messages/second.

Is it possible to write a middleware in Python to optimize this? If so please explain.

Comment: Why would you choose Python for this task?

Comment: Because I am good at python. Anyway what do you suggest?

Comment: What do you want this middleware to do?  Optimize relative to what metric?

Comment: By optimize I mean the middleware should be able to overcome the 30K messages per second limitation of Postgres

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be pretty unrelated to Python or any particular programming language.

These are typical questions to be asked and answers to be given:

1. Are there duplicates? If yes, don't save every message immediately but rather wait for duplicates (for what some kind of RAM-originated cache is required, the simplest one is <thread-safe?> hashtable).
2. Batch your message into large enough packs and then dump them into PostgreSQL all-at-once. You have to determine what is "large enough" based on load tests.
3. Can you drop some of those messages? If your data is not of critical importance, or at least not *all* of it, then you may detect overload by tracking number of pending messages and start to throw incoming stuff away until load becomes acceptable.